# Printing Last Index of a String without using lastIndexOf()

Tags: java, lastindexof

Good Afternoon,
I want to write a method that reaches(asks) two strings and checks whether String2 is in String1 case. If s2 is in s1 it returns the index of
the last occurrence of String2, otherwise it returns -1. It's easy by using lastIndexOf() method but I do not want that. Actually, It would be much better If we do not use handy string methods(except charAt and length).

So, here is my code up to now(It is a really bad code):

```
int contains() {
    Scanner scan0 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter firts string: ");
    String s1 = scan0.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter second string: ");
    String s2 = scan0.nextLine();

    for(int i = 0; i<s1.length(); i++) {
        for(int t = 0; t<s2.length(); t++) {
            char desiredChar = s2.charAt(t);
            char letter = s1.charAt(i);
            if(desiredChar == letter)
                System.out.print(s2.charAt(i));
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

It gives `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` error.

Comment: why you don't want to use builtin methods of Java for this , I mean no one have time to do a research for you here

Comment: I updated the code.

Answer (score 1):

you don't check for the occurrence of the characters of `s2` in `s1`. you will need to go through `s1` `char` by `char` and check if that `char` and the following once are matching `s2`. mean if you have the `strings` as given you iterate through `s1` and take for example the first `char=M` and the next 2 so you have 3 chars just like in `s2`. then you have `Mis` and `the` since they don't match you have to go to the next char and the followings which would then be `iss` and so on until you have matching strings. once you have them you can return the index of the first char of the string in s1.